# jquery how to select other element that is inserted by other JS/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am running discourse and I am trying to modify what happens when one clicks the logout link, I do not want to modify discourse stock javascript...

1. There is an element `elem1` that when clicked inserts another html menu with the logout link. So is it not present when `$(document).ready..` is called. I need to modify what happens on `elem2`.click which is where the logout link is.

I want to do this...

```
$("#elem1").click(function() {
    console.log("step1")
    $("#elem2").click(function () {
        console.log("step2")
        ..do my custom logout 
    })
})
```

but I think jquery is not finding it because it was not there when it first loaded.

Comment: Show the code that actually creates `elem2`

Comment: use event delegation like `$(document).on("click","#elem2", function(){ })`  for attaching event to `#elem2`

Comment: I am trying to find the code that creates it but unfortunately I cannot

Comment: The creating shouldn't be relevant if you're using the solution from vijayP

Comment: @KilianStinson I tried that solution but I still cannot get it to see the second element, nothing happens when it is clicked

Answer (score 1):

Change to this

```
$("#elem2").on('click',function () {
        console.log("step2")
        ..do my custom logout 
    })
```

or if you're using older jQuery:

```
 $("#elem2").live('click',function () {
            console.log("step2")
            ..do my custom logout 
        })
```

Comment: thanks for the try, but it doesn't seem to be working

Comment: Try putting this code outside of the first click.

Comment: still not working for me :( idk why

Comment: Are you sure that the second element selector is correct?

Comment: positive, I've opened the developer console, clicked on the first element and manually typed in the second one to make sure that it selects properly. granted I was using a plain JS `querySelector` instead of jquery but afaik it should be the same